# How do I create a specific number of table rows in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view in my iOS app that should only show five rows. However, under the five rows, it shows a lot of empty rows that continue to the bottom of the screen. I am using dynamic prototypes and I would like to know how to change the total number of rows programmatically. I thought that this function built in would work:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}
```

but it still adds empty cells below the last content cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()